# Replace the domain part of an email address in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Where I am working they are changing their email address for all users from;

@mycompany.com.au

to;

@newcompany.com

Is there a sql statement i can run that will replace the domain name as well as the .com.au to just .com over all email addresses that match @mycompany.com.au?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `update`:

```
update t
    set email = replace(email, '@mycompany.com.au', '@newcompany.com')
    where email like '%@mycompany.com.au';
```

Because the definition of an email only has one `@`, you don't have to worry about the `replace()` finding more than one match.